# How do you get a page to display without waiting for all the others to load with PDF.JS?

Tags: javascript, loading, pdf.js

Good morning !

I am using pdf.js to load a document into a viewer in my website in localhost. But no matter how hard I try, I can't display the first page that finished loading before all the others have finished loading. Suddenly, all the pages are displayed at the same time, but the browser takes 15 seconds before displaying a large pdf... However, I use a loop which displays the pages one by one as soon as they are loaded, so I don't don't really understand. Here is my code:

```
async function displayPdf(url) {
   
      let pdfDoc = null
      pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(pdf => {
        pdfDoc = pdf;
      });
      

      const container = document.getElementById('pdfContainer');

      for (let i = 1; i <=pdfDoc.numPages; i++) {
        const pdfPageDiv = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(pdfPageDiv);
      }
      
      for (let i = 1; i <=pdfDoc.numPages; i++) {
        let page = await pdfDoc.getPage(i)

          const pdfPageDiv = document.getElementById('pdfPage'+i)

          const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

          let scale = 1
          const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
          
          const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

          page.render({ canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport });

          pdfPageDiv.appendChild(canvas);
        
      }
 }
```

The display of all the pages of the pdf are done only at the end of the last iteration of the loop, the pages are not displayed one by one at each end of iteration.

Anyone have an idea to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance for the help you will give me!

How display all the pages one by one at each end of iteration